# Given the inscribed quadrilateral prove that $\frac{ab}{cd}=\frac{y}{x}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given the inscribed quadrilateral prove that $\frac{ab}{cd}=\frac{y}{x}$

[image]

I can get quite a few similar triangles due to several angles inscribing the same arc and the vertical angle. I also have by the power of the point that $(y)(x)=(EC)(AE)$. Now I'm going in circles with the similar triangles so is there another approach I'm not quite seeing in order to get the relationship I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have two pairs of similar triangles (use angle-angle-angle):
\begin{align*}
\Delta AEB \sim \Delta DEC\\[4pt]
\Delta BEC \sim \Delta AED\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Thus, letting $v=CE$, we get
\begin{align*}
\frac{a}{c}&=\frac{y}{v}\\[4pt]
\frac{b}{d}&=\frac{v}{x}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence
$$
\frac{ab}{cd}
=
\left(\frac{a}{c}\right)\!\left(\frac{b}{d}\right)
=
\left(\frac{y}{v}\right)\!\left(\frac{v}{x}\right)
=
\frac{y}{x}
$$